# Problem with Latin Modern in HTML

Tags: html, latin-modern, mathml, markup

I ask this question here because "Latin Modern" is a font, now also available in OpenType format, that's derived from Knuth's "Computer Modern", which is is mainly known by and of interest to the TeX/LaTeX community. It bears on my present work with LaTeX profiles (see my talk at TUG 2010, video available online at river-valley.tv or the print version
in TUGboat, vol. 31 (2010), pp. 240-247).

When I try to use "Latin Modern Math" for inline math along with "Latin Modern Roman" in HTML, even something as simple as the inline HTML version of $x + y$ (using pseudo-mathml [to put Firefox and Chrome on the same playing field] as
foreign HTML 5 markup controlled by CSS) results in the line containing the math being much too "tall".  Changing to either GNU Free Serif or XITSMath makes this issue go away.  Does anyone know why Latin Modern Math spawns such tall boxes when used with HTML?

Small example:  http://www.albany.edu/~hammond/demos/test-xe-math-lm.html

Comment: I don't see anything uncommon. Do I have to have the fonts installed on my system?

Comment: Using my android phone I've any trouble. Even the space between line is correct

Comment: It should look OK with most fonts.  If you don't know whether you have Latin Modern, you probably don't.  If you have TeXLive and fontconfig in Linux, then you probably do.  With Firefox or Chrome use the "inspector" to find out what font is used.

Comment: If I had a webfont version of Latin Modern, I suppose I could serve that with the example page, but I don't have one.

Comment: @WilliamF.Hammond Fréderic Wang has web font version of math fonts: https://github.com/fred-wang/MathFonts

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2891/michal-h21, Many thanks. The woff-ed Latin Modern there does seem to be OK.